Python Logs From Azure Function Not Showing in Datadog
I'm trying to send logs from a Python function in Azure into Datadog using their API via the V2 library. Some logs are getting lost and I can't figure out why.
Here is my handler (implements logging.handler)
import atexit
import logging
import queue
import threading
import time
import random

from datadog_api_client.exceptions import ApiException
from datadog_api_client.v2 import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v2.api import logs_api
from datadog_api_client.v2.models import HTTPLog, HTTPLogItem

from ts.common.logging.utils import generate_tags
from ts.domain.objects import Environment


class DatadogCustomLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(
        self,
        service_name="default",
        host_name: str = None,
        environment: Environment = None,
        batch_size: int = 50,
        flush_interval: int = 5,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super(DatadogCustomLogHandler, self).__init__()
        self.service_name = service_name
        self.host_name = host_name
        self.environment = environment
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.flush_interval = flush_interval

        self.logs_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.is_shutting_down = threading.Event()
        self.logs_batch_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._worker)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

        atexit.register(self.cleanup)

    def emit(self, record):
        # Prevent blocking the application; drop the log if shutting down.

        if not self.is_shutting_down.is_set():
            try:
                self.logs_queue.put_nowait(self.format_record(record))
            except queue.Full:
                pass  # Optionally, handle or log the drop.

    def format_record(self, record):
        # Convert record to dict or desired format for Datadog

        log_data = record.__dict__.get("msg", {})
        if isinstance(log_data, str):
            message = log_data
            properties = {}
        else:
            message = log_data.pop("event", "")
            properties = log_data

        log_entry = {
            "message": message,
            "properties": properties,
            "level": record.levelname,
        }

        return log_entry

    def _submit_logs(self, logs_batch):
        max_retries = 3  # Maximum number of retries
        backoff_factor = 2  # Backoff multiplier
        initial_delay = 0.5  # Initial delay in seconds

        with ApiClient(Configuration()) as api_client:
            api_instance = logs_api.LogsApi(api_client)
            log_items = []

            tags = generate_tags(
                service_name=self.service_name,
                host_name=self.host_name,
                environment=self.environment,
            )

            for log in logs_batch:
                log_item = HTTPLogItem(
                    **log["properties"],
                    ddsource="python",
                    message=log["message"],
                    service=self.service_name,
                    ddtags=tags,
                    host=self.host_name,
                )
                log_items.append(log_item)

            body = HTTPLog(log_items)

            for attempt in range(max_retries + 1):
                try:
                    api_instance.submit_log(body)
                    break  # Break the loop if the submission was successful
                except ApiException as e:
                    if attempt < max_retries:
                        sleep_time = (backoff_factor**attempt) * initial_delay
                        # Adding jitter to prevent Thundering Herd problem
                        sleep_time += random.uniform(0, 0.2)
                        print(
                            f"Retry #{attempt + 1}: An error occurred while submitting logs to Datadog: {e}. "
                            f"Retrying in {sleep_time} seconds."
                        )
                        time.sleep(sleep_time)
                    else:
                        print(
                            f"Failed to submit logs to Datadog after {max_retries} attempts: {e}"
                        )

    def _worker(self):
        while not self.is_shutting_down.is_set() or not self.logs_queue.empty():
            current_batch = []
            while not self.logs_queue.empty() and len(current_batch) < self.batch_size:
                try:
                    log = self.logs_queue.get_nowait()
                    current_batch.append(log)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            if current_batch:
                with self.logs_batch_lock:
                    self._submit_logs(current_batch)

            if not self.is_shutting_down.is_set():
                time.sleep(self.flush_interval)

    def _shutdown_worker(self):
        self.is_shutting_down.set()
        self.thread.join()

    def cleanup(self):
        self._shutdown_worker()

    def close(self):
        self.cleanup()
        super(DatadogCustomLogHandler, self).close()

And this is the function I use to instantiate my logger, which calls DatadogCustomHandler:
import logging
import socket

import structlog

from ts.common.helpers.validation import getenv_with_warning, validate_var_type
from ts.common.logging.handler import DatadogCustomLogHandler
from ts.domain.objects import Environment

host_name = socket.gethostname()

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
        structlog.processors.EventRenamer("message"),
        structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
    context_class=dict,
)


def init_datadog_logger(
    service_name: str, min_log_level: int = logging.INFO, logger_name: str = None
) -> structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger:
    env = getenv_with_warning("ENV")
    env_service_name = getenv_with_warning("SERVICE_NAME")
    dd_log_batch_size = int(getenv_with_warning("DD_LOG_BATCH_SIZE", 50))

    validate_var_type("service_name", service_name, str, is_optional=False)

    environment = next(
        (member for member in Environment.__members__.values() if member.value == env),
        Environment.LOCAL,
    )

    logger_name = logger_name or env_service_name or "default_logger"
    stdlib_logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger = structlog.wrap_logger(stdlib_logger)

    if stdlib_logger.handlers:
        print(
            f"Logger {logger_name if logger_name else 'root'} already initialized, skipping initialization."
        )
        return logger

    stdlib_logger.setLevel(min_log_level)

    if environment:
        datadog_custom_handler = DatadogCustomLogHandler(
            service_name=service_name,
            host_name=host_name,
            environment=environment,
            level=min_log_level,
            batch_size=dd_log_batch_size,
        )
        stdlib_logger.addHandler(datadog_custom_handler)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("logfile.log")
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stdlib_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    stdlib_logger.propagate = False

    return logger

For instance I would create a timed function in Azure that outputs 2500 arbitrary logs every 10 minutes. I would instantiate the log this way:
logger = init_datadog_logger(service_name=os.getenv("SERVICE_NAME"), logger_name=os.getenv("SERVICE_NAME"))

However from those 2500 logs, maybe only 2100-2200 make it in at any one point. It's the same when I run it locally, but maybe not the same loss rate. How do I check for what is going on, and how to improve it?
